# Reading a text file with java

Tags: java, string, parsing, arraylist

I'm writing a "Move To Front" encoder that reads a file given then parses the file into a list. It works fine with the encoding, however it only works with files of only one line, I think the problem is in the while loop.

Here is the code:

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) !=
       null) // While the line file is not empty after reading a line from teh text file split the line into strings
{
  splitArray = line.split(" ");
}

for (int i = 0; i <= splitArray.length - 1;
     i++) // for every string in the array test if it exists already then output data accordinly
{
  if (FirstPass.contains(splitArray[i])) {
    System.out.println(FirstPass.lastIndexOf(splitArray[i]));
    FirstPass.addFirst(splitArray[i]);
    FirstPass.removeLastOccurrence(splitArray[i]);
  } else if (!FirstPass.contains(splitArray[i])) {
    FirstPass.addFirst(splitArray[i]);
    System.out.println("0 " + splitArray[i]);
  }
}

System.out.println(" ");
for (String S : FirstPass) {
  System.out.println(S);
}
```

Comment: Sorry br is a buffered reader

Comment: Please edit your post and fix the indentation.  Replace tabs with the appropriate number of spaces.

Comment: Your first while-loop reads the entire file and discards all the data except for the last line.

Comment: @JimGarrison It's nicely formatted.  He's just using an ugly brace style.  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code that parses the splitArray is outside the while loop .. so only the last line will get processed.

To process every line, put that entire `for ()` block inside the while loop ..

```
while((line = br.readLine()) != null) // While the line file is not empty after reading a line from teh text file split the line into strings
{
    splitArray = line.split(" ");


    for(int i = 0; i <= splitArray.length - 1; i++)     // for every string in the array test if it exists already then output data accordinly
    {
        //..........
    } // end for
} // end while
```

Comment: Thank you so much Kal I knew it would be something small and stupid. Thanks for taking hte time to answer my question

Answer (score 0):

Braces in wrong spot:

```
while((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
{
    splitArray = line.split(" ");
}  // This } shouuldn't be here...
```

Comment: Removing the brace will just make the code compile-time error.

Comment: @MathSquared11235 100% correct. I'm pointing out the general area of the problem, not giving complete code for something this localized.